# How to create admin for react app without login form?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react app and I need the app to allow the administrator to upload photos from the app and not from the code.
The app does not have a login form, I want to know how I can create an admin without a login form.

Comment: the only way is to use mobile ip address instead of login form and force admin to use only that device to upload

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not managing users, means everybody is anonymous.

Let's start with this question:

- How do you pretend to classify which is an `ADMIN USER` and which a `"REGULAR_USER`?